# Scrap image_urls from a dynamic scrollable web page, its image_urls are disappeared when it is scrolled to other location

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, dynamic

I have to scrap a dynamic scrollable website, and extract image urls. The problem is that when the scroller comes to a location. All the images from the other locations are vanished. How to extract all the image URLs.

I am using the following Python selenium code, it doesn't extract all the URLs from the page.

```
wd.get('https://dynamicWebPage')
scroll_pause_time = 2
screen_height = wd.execute_script("return window.innerHeight")

last_scroll_height = wd.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
items = [] 
while True:
    wd.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)

    new_scroll_height = wd.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    print(new_scroll_height, last_scroll_height)
    if new_scroll_height == last_scroll_height:
      break
    last_scroll_height = new_scroll_height
    elements = wd.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//a")
    items.extend([element.text for element in elements])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try different ways to scroll, maybe by pressing some combo of buttons, e.g.:

```py
driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.END)
```

or just end, or pressing the down arrow with some sleep in between.